# How can I get my friends from Google+ with the Java API?

Tags: java, google-plus

I'm interested in getting several friends from different circles in Google+. I am using java google plus API. Is it possible to get the people from my circles? How?

Thanks

Comment: this example is my last test https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/listByActivity

Comment: btw, which "java google plus API" are you using? link?

Comment: @Bozho http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Comment: aha. I found that a bit tedious to use, so I made http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, currently Google+ doesn't offer an option to get people from circles (yet).

The best you can do is get the people that have acted upon your activities: 1. get your own activities 2. Get the plusoners, resharers and commenters

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Google Contact API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html) to do that. But you will have only name of user and no information about e-mail or circles.