# How to get list of friend in my circle in Google +

Tags: php, api, google-plus

I want to get the list of friends in my circle (Google+). I am not getting that list; my code is as follows:

```
    require_once('assets/google/Google_Client.php');
    require_once('assets/google/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php');
    require_once('assets/google/contrib/Google_PlusService.php');
    $gClient = new Google_Client();
    $gClient->setApplicationName('Login to Google');
    $gClient->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
    $gClient->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);
    $gClient->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY);
    $gClient->setScopes($scope);
    $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);
    $google_plus = new Google_PlusService($gClient);
    if (isset($_GET['code'])){ 
        $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' .filter_var($google_redirect_url,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        return;
    }
    $user = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
```

I am getting my details by calling the above function

```
$peoples = $google_plus->people->listPeople('me','visible');
```

When I use the above call to get the list of people, I get an insufficient permission (403). Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: visit This https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/.. There Are just some scripts they provide which u can use in ur site

Comment: You are substituting `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID`, `GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET`, etc., with real values, aren't you?

Comment: Did you enable the api from console? Are you trying this locally or on server?

Comment: What is the value of `$scope`?

Comment: @deadman your comment is not related to the comment at all.

Answer (score 0):

As per 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22303675/465974 or 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8136038/465974 
 it's not possible to get friends in specific circle

 
However as per 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17943068/465974 or 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062671/465974 
you can get list of friends